# убрать повторяющиеся слова при помощи регулярных выражений oracle

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle

Используя регулярные выражения нужно убрать повторы слов из выражения 'yes yes, you a very very bad bad boy'. Используйте таблицу DUAL. Вот мой запрос, которым получилось это сделать.

```
   SELECT 
      REGEXP_REPLACE ('yes yes, you a very very bad bad boy', '(\w{3}) (\w{3}, \w{3} \w \w{4}) (\w{4} \w{3}) (\w{3} \w{3})', '\2 \4' ) as 
      final_view
  FROM
    dual;
```

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, другим способом. Более рациональным

Comment: В регулярке какая-то фигня...

Comment: я исправил. запрос прошёл. Меня интересует еще какой-нибудь более лаконичный способ это сделать

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически, вот так:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('yes yes, you a very very bad bad boy', '(\b\w+\b)(\s+\1\b)+', '\1')
```

```js
console.log('yes yes, you a very very bad bad boy'.replace(/(\b\w+\b)(\s+\1\b)+/g, '$1'))
```

Comment: так почему-то не отрабатывает. возвращает изначальную строку

Comment: в oracle синтаксис регулярного выражения отличается. т.к. такое решение не проходит

Comment: @It'sme, ну так исправь на их синтаксис?